# Xamarin forms Carrousel and take a picture async

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, carousel, media

I have been trying to replace my carrousel images with t new photos from my phone camera or album, but for some binding reason, they don't display on the carousel.
I am using Xamarin Media Plugin.
any picture I select should display on the carousel. I have been trying everything in here. IMAGE URL works fine, stored images in the resources folder, works as well. but, for some reason display the images from the media is been a nightmare.
You can clone my sample project @  [GITHUB](https://github.com/pamela032709/Xam-Carrousel)

I will appreciate Any help.

Comment: I do expect not to waste people time that's why I posted. did you read what I asked? I don't know exactly how to display the cam/album images into the carousel. what part of relevant do you need? because I don't. either you know or you don't know. don't waste my time reading your rude comments.

Comment: By the way , a good programmer knows about GITHUB and how easy makes to share peoples code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the GITHUB project, easy to understand why no relevant code here, it will require the whole sample project. It seems the carousel is not getting updated when uploading an image, binding?? I am still checking.

Comment: Thanks a lot user!